# Programmatically generated mesh vertex colors not showing up in Unity?

Tags: unity, vertex, color

I'm sorry if this is an obvious thing to solve but I just can't figure it out...did I miss something...I've generated a mesh and during vertices generation I've also set its colors (and colors32 just in case) by reading those values from a ply file, and afterwards I've added a number of vertex color shaders but none of them will show the vertex point colors in play mode, it's either solid black or just like I added no material to the mesh (which I've tried doing manually in play mode too).

Did I miss something please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, it's hard to tell with you not showing any code or explaining further what you've done :)

Does your shader handles vertex colors ?

If not then here's a quick example:

```
Shader "Unlit Vertex Color"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            // make fog work
            #pragma multi_compile_fog

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 color : COLOR;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 color : COLOR;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            fixed _Brightness;
            fixed _Gamma;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                o.color = v.color;
                o.color.w = 1.0;
                //UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // sample the texture
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                col *= i.color;
                // apply fog
                UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

I just pass `COLOR` semantic to where necessary and blend the result with the pixel.

You can get started writing your own by templating some of the shaders from the builtin ones:

https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive

If you want Standard shader with vertex colors (unofficial):

https://forum.unity.com/threads/standard-shader-with-vertex-colors.316529/

Also, Unity is apparently [going to release](https://forum.unity.com/threads/standard-shader-with-vertex-colors.316529/page-7#post-3959431) an official standard shader with vertex colors.

Comment: You Sir are a savior! I had five different shaders of the net and none gave me the points, I was going crazy enough and started looking at values (I noticed something I'm confused about, value in color.r/g/b is float 0..1 and color32.r/g/b is int 0..255, I'd ask how but that's for another question probably the one where I'll ask if I need color at all when color32 is set since unity says 32's better for performance)...but just adding your shader made it work (honestly don't know why others didn't - I can't read them but one said unlit vertex color too - where do you learn about shaders plz)?

Comment: For colors I think you should use whichever notation you prefer, e.g. `Color` is natural since it maps from `0.0` to `1.0`, then later, if you notice performance problems by profiling you will want to adjust places in your code to emit `Color32` instead. Keep in mind they both have implicit operators to each other so be careful when optimizing. Now for the shaders I learned the hard way: the 'builtin shaders' link I've mentioned. Here's a tip, use Notepad++ folder search on them, it'll be less intimidating and you'll get a better understanding overall on what is used where.

Comment: Just one question when I got you here...since I can't seem to get it to work programmatically...do I need to anything else beside :             MeshRenderer mr = g.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            Material newMat = Resources.Load("vertex", typeof(Material)) as Material;
            mr.material = newMat; (vertex is the name of the material I assigned the shader too, and it works when I do it in the property, when in game play mode) *Thank you in advance again*

Comment: I do the following by code, get my mesh, add `MeshFilter` component and set its `mesh`, add `MeshRenderer` component and set its `material`; and obviously if I have a texture I set `material.mainTexture`.

Comment: You mean it doesn't work during play mode or what ?

Comment: It wouldn't work setting it programmatically and showing up in play mode with **Material material = (Material)Resources.Load("Assets/vertex", typeof(Material));** // I also tried with "vertex" only and "Assets/Resources/vertex" (it returned null value allways) but this functions:
**if (material == null) material = (Material)UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Material>("Assets/vertex.mat");**
(I also tried with .mat in the above so it's not the full path there, as I gather that should be the name in the Project pane, and the path there so root/vertex???)

Comment: `AssetDatabase` will of course not work since it's from `UnityEditor`, what about adding a `public Material material;` property on your `MonoBehaviour`, drag and drop your material to it in the Inspector; then retrieve this material in your script instead ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90138/discussion-between-gi1-and-aybe).